# Selective birthday notification

Tags: 8.0, contacts, calendars

I've got lots of friends and when I connected my Windows phone device with my Facebook account, it automatically downloaded all the information there is for all my contacts including their birthday.

However, I don't care about all the birthdays. And my device keeps reminding me I should send a note saying "Happy birthday". Sure I can dismiss them, but I was wondering if there was a way I could select for which friend do I want to get notification? Or at least if there is an option to completely disable reminder?

Note that I want to see people's birthday in my agenda, I just don't want to get notified!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Edit:*** Microsoft has re-branded the Calendar UI. I have modified instructions below (without updating the screenshots).

---

The good news is yes, you can disable notification for birthday reminders that are coming from Facebook.

You cannot do this from within the calendar app but you can do it by using your Windows Live Calendar. The steps:

1. Log on to [calendar.live.com](http://calendar.live.com)
2. Once you have logged in, on the top right beside your name, there is a gear icon <s>below you name, there is an "Options" link</s>. Click on it and then click `Options`.

3- On the next page, there is a section titled "Edit your reminder and Calendar settings" and one of the calendar's there should be "Birthday Calendar"

[image]

4- Click on your "Birthday Calendar" and then you should see something like this:

[image]

As you can see under "Notifications" you can change whether you get reminders on your phone- it is quite flexible.

Now, if you want to be able to still get reminders for some people but not all then you can add a calendar with birthdays added only for the people you like and enable reminders for those people :)